# Proper way to "fix" closed question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, closed-questions

I messed up asking my first question on Seasoned Advice, which was rightfully put "on-hold" as off-topic.  For reference:

[Can I use oil in marinades for dehydrated mushrooms?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59556/how-to-properly-marinate-dehydrated-mushrooms)

I think I fixed it, but in the process I probably turned the original into a completely different question.  Nonetheless, the question never came back from "on-hold," but instead progressed to "closed."

Should I wait and see if it gets reopened, or should I make a new post for my new, proper question and delete the old one?

Answer (score 3):

Questions that were edited after being put on hold do go in the reopen queue, and yours was indeed in the queue, and has collected two reopen votes! But given the rather small number of users who review that queue (hint hint, high-rep folks) it can take a while for questions to get up to five votes.

So if you want it to get reopened, the best thing to do is probably to flag it. But we mods are happy to handle things, and can take care of it right away with a single vote.

In this specific case, it's a little iffy since you'd already gotten an answer based on the original form of the question, and as you say, you changed it quite a bit from the original form (rather than just making it more specific). But... eh, no need to make more trouble - I'll just reopen it.

---

In general, it's certainly fine to delete your own closed questions if you're confident they won't be salvaged. It's also certainly fine to post new, good questions. So in this case, sure, you could also have deleted the bad polling question and tried again with the real specific question, instead of editing.

The other thing that's definitely bad is to repost a question without really changing it substantially (whether or not you delete the old one); at that point you'd just be making it harder for people to keep track of both posts, and possibly trying to evade the closing. This includes attempting to fix a question that really just needed a little editing, not a total rewrite into a new question. But that's not what was going on here, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the reopen, but if you hadn't helped me out, would it have been gauche to delete and retry with a better question?  Also, I didn't even notice the flag feature where is it explained?

Comment: @Frank There should be a "flag" link along with "share" and "edit" under every post.

Comment: Yeah, I see the link, but I don't know what the intended use of it is.  Is it not there to report posts breaking the rules, or is it acceptable for use as a catch-all "mods please look at this" function?  I don't want to annoy the mods...

Comment: @Frank When you click "flag" there are some predefined flagging reasons. If any of those apply, it's definitely something worth flagging. There's also a custom reason; if you think something needs our attention (especially if it's something *only* mods would be able to handle), flag it. If it's helpful it'll probably just silently get marked as helpful, but we can respond with a note if we need to. You can see your flag history by going to your profile and clicking on the link by "helpful flags" - except you don't have one right now since you've never flagged anything.

Comment: See also links in the [StackExchange-wide FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Also not linked directly from there, [What are acceptable reasons for flagging as “Requires Moderator attention”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10848/133299) - answers are mostly the longer version of what I said, I think.

Comment: Oh, and the basic documentation is in on the [privileges](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page: at 15 rep you get the ability to [Flag Posts](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).